# Creating a average column for specific dates in tableau desktop and or prep

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have created a tableau prep flow combining 4 different data sources. I was able to create a formula that categorizes 4 different data types...

1. Historical
2. Current
3. Plan
4. ETC

the "current" data type consist of multiple weekly dates 6/30 | 7/7 | 7/14 | 7/21 these dates are consistent with my companies accounting weeks.

The other data types are standard consistent dates 6/1 |7/1 | 8/1 etc..

How can I create a formula that sum the total hours within each current week and then calculates the average of all current weekly dates?